# Using "$and" and "$in" together

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `friends` which i am using to store all the friends and has the following fields

> id , userid, friendid

I have a collection `notes` which stores user notes and has the following fields

> id, userid , ownerid , privateorpublic

The rule is a user can only see notes he/she has created or notes created by his/her friends or notes that are public

To fetch that information i am writing my query this way. First, get all the ids of my friends separated by a comma. I dont know how to write the query to return comma delimited values but this query below I am hoping will return all the firneds of the user by the given id:

```
db.friends.find({ { friendid: { userid: 'jhdshh37838gsjj' } }
```

then get the notes where are either created by a friend or are public notes or are notes belonging to user

```
db.notes.find({ownerid:'jhdshh37838gsjj', privateorpublic:'public',{ $in: [ "3ghd8e833", "78hhyaysgd" ] }
```

I am new to MongoDB. Are my queries right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find query syntax : `db.collection.find({queryFieldName: queryFieldValue}, {requiredFieldName: 1, NotRequiredFieldName: 0})`

Thus, translating first query, you'd get "get me all documents from collection friends where friendId equals a string `{'userId':'Id'}`" which is not desired.

Query for "Get me all friend Ids of userid jhdshh37838gsjj and don't print anything else in results" : `db.collection.find({userId:'jhdshh37838gsjj'}, {friendId:1, _id:0})`

However, this'll not give output as comma separated values. You'll get output as follows (because every document is an independent object):

```
{friendId: 1}
{friendId: 2}
```

$in requires array as input and not comma separated values. To make an array of field values for a $in query, you need to some extra work like:

```
var friendIdsArr = [] //Initiate an array to store friend Ids
db.friends.find({'userId':'jhdshh37838gsjj'},{'friendId':1,'_id':0}).forEach(function(x) {friendIdsArr.push(x.friendId);} ); //Foreach result in query, push value  to array.
```

The `friendIdsArr` will be `[1,2]`

`db.notes.find({'ownerId':'jhdshh37838gsjj', 'privateOrPublic':'public',{$in: ["friendId": friendIdsArr]})`
will give results, json documents, matching the given conditions.

Interestingly, your `notes` collection doesn't have a `note` field.

I'd recommend you to read [mongodb official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/) and make a single query instead of two different queries.